# Load bearing steel post rusted

Tags: load-bearing, steel, post, rust-removal

At my mum's place, there's a steel post holding up the lintel over a sliding door because the wall next to the door has a box air con in it. However, it's badly rusted at the bottom due to the rain we've been receiving:

[image: badly rusted metal post next to doorway]

How can I repair/reinforce this post?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: It is probably worth removing the loose rust to see what condition it really is in.  It may not be in as bad condition as it initially looks.

Comment: FYI:   Box air con = Box air conditioner.

Comment: That isn't rusted due to recent rain. It's been a years-long degradation process.

Comment: When replacing this post (or getting it repaired), you may want to make sure that there's a good moisture barrier between the steel and the concrete block. Those blocks will wick moisture up from the ground and bring it to the hidden side of the post rusting it from the back to the front. No amount of paint maintenance on the side you can see will prevent that. Not sure what that moisture barrier should be, but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 10):

Load bearing makes life a bit more difficult.

Replacement of the whole post is probably the best option, but a licensed welder should be able to cut out the bad section and weld in a new piece.

Will need a temporary support post while the work is going on.

Welding in a new piece might not be possible due to local codes, check with local building department/inspector.

You want a license/professional welder, not the guy a few doors down who has a welder has a hobby.

Comment: Do you know if a post like this sit on the ground or below the ground? Or does it sit on top of the bricks?

Comment: Looks like the bottom of the rust is the base of the post.  Any load bearing post must be on something to support it, cement.  Would need someone there to check if it is a real load bearing post(might be inside the wall) or just a covering, it looks more structural.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the post is sitting on the block foundation wall and my recommendation is to provide a temporary support and remove this post. cutting it out and trying to weld in place would be very difficult.

It appears like the post is rusted through on the right and if that is the case it may be rusted out all the way up where it is in contact.

So support the wall from the inside a temp wall to hold the weight, remove the post and install a new one.

I use capped or a T plate on posts or a u strap to hold in place and place materials like tar paper / roofing felt or a sill seal under the post to prevent the same from happening again(as fast).

Their may be a nail plate or T plate but some are toe nailed more demo after a temp wall is built to handle the weight will show what will be needed.